# Accidentally bad versioned package

Tags: python, django, pypi

I released a package for django to pypi, it was my first time and i think there was a mistake.

I started [my package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/qhonuskan-votes) from 1.0.0, but it should be 0.1 on first release (http://semver.org/)

Can i undo my upload to pypi and redo it as version 0.1?

Comment: Most package management systems will never let you go back, not sure about pypi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can log in on pypi and simply delete the uploaded package.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that, although you can delete your bad versioned package, you CAN NOT re-upload a new package WITH SAME VERSION NUMBER, and [which is good](https://github.com/pypa/packaging-problems/issues/74).